# WordPress: snag first image from a gallery

Tags: image, wordpress, function, loops

On my homepage, I'm trying to output the first image of each post, and I'm able to successfully do that using this code in my functions.php:

```
function catch_that_image() {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];

if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
$first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
}
return $first_img;
}
```

and then I call it in my loop like this:

```
<img src=”<?php catch_that_image(); ?>” />
```

The problem with this method is that it won't work if I place a gallery in that same post. I'm confused because the output of the post still renders the img markup, and my assumption is that catch_that_image() should snag that markup? Is my thinking incorrect? Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gallery is placed inside your post using a WordPress short-tag. The shorttag is transformed into HTML-image tags when the filter for transforming the shorttag is applied.

The following might work, but I am not sure:

```
function catch_that_image() {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();


$transformed_content = apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content);


$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $transformed_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];

if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
$first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
}
return $first_img;
}
```

Please let me know if this was useful or if it was pointing you into the right direction!

Codex Links:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Comment: Its rendering text path of the image but not image itself any solution?

Comment: My mistake I was trying to get it without image tag :P anyways thanks but now I want to add my custom size. any idea how to do?

Comment: You can also try to get images via image attachment from posts. Maybe this discussion is helpful. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-the-images-attached-to-post-expect-the-first-image

Maybe you can do a custom database query, to check which image is attached to the post. You can get the image, passing a size using its attachment ID.